# Web2py custom login form not submitting?

Tags: javascript, python, html, forms, web2py

I'm trying to customize my login form for web2py, but when I add the fields and submit button it is not doing anything. The code in view for the form looks like this:

```
{{include 'web2py_ajax.html'}}
<h2>
{{=T('Sign Up') if request.args(0) == 'register' else T('Log In') if 
request.args(0) == 'login' else T(request.args(0).replace('_',' 
').title())}}
</h2>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="web2py_user_form" class="col-lg-6">
        {{
=form.custom.begin
        if request.args(0)=='login':
            if not 'register' in auth.settings.actions_disabled:
                form.add_button(T('Sign Up'),URL(args='register', vars=
{'_next': request.vars._next} if request.vars._next else 
None),_class='btn btn-default')
            pass
            if not 'request_reset_password' in 
auth.settings.actions_disabled:
                form.add_button(T('Lost 
Password'),URL(args='request_reset_password'),_class='btn btn-default')
            pass
=form.custom.widget.email
=form.custom.widget.password
=form.custom.submit
   =form.custom.end
        pass

        }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried pretty much everything at this point, but the login button still doesn't submit the fields, is there anything else that I should be doing?

EDIT: So I figured out that my code isn't working when I try to add HTML in between the python. I get an error saying that I am missing "pass" in view. Here is the code i am trying to implement:
    {{=form.custom.begin}}

```
        {{
        if request.args(0)=='login':
                if not 'register' in auth.settings.actions_disabled:
                form.add_button(T('Sign Up'),URL(args='register', vars=
{'_next': request.vars._next} if request.vars._next else 
None),_class='btn btn-default')
            pass
            if not 'request_reset_password' in . 
auth.settings.actions_disabled:
                form.add_button(T('Lost 
Password'),URL(args='request_reset_password'),_class='btn btn-default')
            pass
        }}
Email Address:
    {{=form.custom.widget.email}}

Password:
    {{=form.custom.widget.password}}
    {{=form.custom.submit
    =form.custom.end

    pass}}
```

This throws an error saying I'm missing "pass", however when I remove the html "Email:" and "Password:" from the code so that it is only python the form works. How can I make the html work in this code?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me though I am not sure what customisation you are working towards.  With this, I think the custom form effectively overrides much of the default form content e.g. you are left with only the login option. - have a look - copy and paste it in - with some further tweaking you should be able to get the rest back if you want it.

Note:
where I have placed the form.custom.begin
that I have moved one of your 'pass' statements up
and I reformatted the form.custom.end - see braces.
(I think that's it)

Not sure all of this was needed or if this is strictly correct but it may get you over the hump and allow you to move on... sorry the format looks dreadful - this is my first answer on stackoverflow.  Good Luck!

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<h2>
{{=T('Sign Up') if request.args(0) == 'register' else T('Log In') if   request.args(0) == 'login' else T(request.args(0).replace('_',' ').title())}}
</h2>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="web2py_user_form" class="col-lg-6">
        {{=form.custom.begin}} 
        {{
        if request.args(0)=='login':
            if not 'register' in auth.settings.actions_disabled:
                form.add_button(T('Sign Up'),URL(args='register', vars={'_next': request.vars._next} if request.vars._next else None),_class='btn btn-default')
            pass
            if not 'request_reset_password' in 

auth.settings.actions_disabled:
                    form.add_button(T('Lost  Password'),URL(args='request_reset_password'),_class='btn btn-default')
            pass
        pass
        }}

        Email Address:
            {{=form.custom.widget.email}}

        Password:
            {{=form.custom.widget.password}}
            {{=form.custom.submit}}

        {{=form.custom.end}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{{block page_js}}
<script>
    jQuery("#web2py_user_form input:visible:enabled:first").focus();
{{if request.args(0)=='register':}}
    web2py_validate_entropy(jQuery('#auth_user_password'),100);
{{elif request.args(0)=='change_password':}}
    web2py_validate_entropy(jQuery('#no_table_new_password'),100);
{{pass}}
</script>
{{end page_js}}
```